# Setting options for typeahead, using Angular-ui Bootstrap

Tags: angularjs, typeahead, angular-ui-bootstrap

Using typeahead, I am trying to set a couple of options, which are available as standard Bootstrap [typeahead options](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#typeahead)

Using the following code, I'm able to set the "minLength" property by putting it in-line as "typeahead-min-length", but doing the same with "items" as "typeahead-items" does not.  Is there a different/better/standard way to do this?  Is there a way to attach an array of options to  $scope?

```
<div class='container-fluid' ng-controller="TestController">

<input type="text" ng-model="selected" 
typeahead="foo for foo in foo | filter:$viewValue" typeahead-items='5' typeahead-min-length='3'>

<pre>{{selected| json}}</pre>  </div>
```

Update: I'm trying to stick with just AngularJS, and not use jQuery

This is my controller:

```
  myAppModule.controller('TestController', function($http,$scope) {
  $scope.selected = undefined;

  $http.get('data/sample.json')
       .then(function(results){
          $scope.foo = results.data; 
      });
  });
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why don't you use the JS way to initialize typeahead:

```
$('input.typeahead').typeahead({
    source: array_of_value_here,
    minLength: 1,
    items: 5,
    // your option values ...
});
```

**EDIT:**

I see, the AngularJS way, you can use `limitTo`:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="selected" typeahead="foo for foo in foo | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:5" typeahead-min-length='3'>
```

Comment: trying to stick with AngularJS

Comment: That's perfect Hieu, thanks.  May I ask the URL for the doc you used to figure that out?  Works like a charm, thanks.

Comment: It should be the AngularJS one: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter:limitTo , it's also mentioned a bit here: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/angular-ui/ZZQug6nRLwQ/FTSQYy5zszsJ . Hope it helps ;)

Comment: +1 for limitTo, rather than the jQuery way. Even though it looks like an ng-repeat it didn't actually occur to me that limitTo would be an option