# Is there any way to start searching after 3 seconds?

Tags: jquery, grid

`function fnActionBegin(args) {
    isFirstRequest=true;
    var searchValue = $("#searchBox").val();

```
if (searchValue != "Search") {
    this.model.query._params.push({ key: "searchKey", value: searchValue });
}
var filerSettings = [], i;

if (args.model.filterSettings.filteredColumns.length > 0) {
    for (i = 0; i < args.model.filterSettings.filteredColumns.length; i++) {
        var column = args.model.filterSettings.filteredColumns[i];
        filerSettings.push({ 'PropertyName': column.field, 'FilterType': column.operator, 'FilterKey': column.value });
    }

    this.model.query._params.push({ key: "filterCollection", value: filerSettings });
}

args.model.query._params.push({
    key: "isSearch",
    value: $("#Section #list").length > 0 
});
```

}`
I nearly having thousand of records and I am using three ways of searching in my project.

**1. Angular search**

**2. Server side search**

**3. Client side search**

I need to speed up the search results, `(i.e)` not after every character typed.
I need to show the results after user typed the word after 3 seconds.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please refer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17734270/setting-options-for-typeahead-using-angular-ui-bootstrap).

Answer (score 0):

Assume that you are using js to handle an event of ***keyup*** from keyboard to trigger the search.

- *You can change to **blur event**, only search when you leave focus
  that search box.*
- *You can use a **$timeout** to delay the AJAX call to 3000
  miliseconds.*

[How to use a $timeout in AngularJS](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout)

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have added my code sample above. Can you help me with code ?